# Rails/GraphQL/Devise: Any good alternative to Devise for applications running GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, graphql

I've used Devise for a long time and I love all the features it comes with. The only problem is that it has a RESTful style of authentication that doesn't work very well with GraphQL.

Is there something fully featured (e.g. email resets, account confirming and  locking etc) like devise that works well with a GraphQL API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using [this](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) together with my GraphQL APIs. Not perfect but it works fine having the graphql route and the `auth` REST endpoint together.

Also a friend and I are working on precisely that [over here](https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise). It's a work in progress but we expect to have something functional soon. You still have to have a separate route for your GraphQL auth schema, as those queries need to be unauthenticated (login, register) and you always want to authenticate in your main schema. So it might look like this

```
POST /graphql      (main schema)
POST /graphql/auth (auth schema)
```

**UPDATE** We have released v0.14.0 now. Still some things to work on, but I wouldn't call it a work in progress anymore as we've been working on it for over a year. Here is the link for the [Graphql Devise Gem](https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise), again.

Comment: fantastic! I'll have to follow this project. Maybe you could use an extra hand or I can test the gem etc. Good idea about the auth route under graphql.

Comment: Right now we still have to figure out a couple of things with the approach we are taking, but once it's more defined we'll definitely start taking PRs. Also, just using the gem once it's published will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: You got it. I followed the project last night. When I get some free time, I'm going to play around with it. I think a nice addition might be a sample Rails app repo that uses the gem? I'll reach out to you via email since this is more off topic now.